# Why graphs are so important

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, computer-science

The notion of graph seems to be of a huge importance in Computer Science. A very rich Graph Theory was developed, and theoretical problems are being solved all the time.

What I don't understand, is **what** makes graph objects so important? **Which** intrinsic properties of graphs make them so useful, or **more** useful than other math objects?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-graph-theory-important

Answer (score 2):

Graphs are a common method to visually illustrate relationships in the data. The purpose of a graph is to present data that are too numerous or complicated to be described adequately in the text and in less space.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory#Computer_science) says,

Graphs can be used to model many types of relations and processes in physical, biological, social and information systems. Many practical problems can be represented by graphs. Emphasizing their application to real-world systems, the term network is sometimes defined to mean a graph in which attributes (e.g. names) are associated with the vertices and edges.

In computer science, graphs are used to represent networks of communication, data organization, computational devices, the flow of computation, etc. For instance, the link structure of a website can be represented by a directed graph, in which the vertices represent web pages and directed edges represent [links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink) from one page to another. A similar approach can be taken to problems in social media, travel, biology, computer chip design, mapping the progression of neuro-degenerative diseases, and many other fields. The development of [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm) to handle graphs is therefore of major interest in computer science. The [transformation of graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_transformation) is often formalized and represented by [graph rewrite systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_rewriting). Complementary to [graph transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_rewriting) systems focusing on rule-based in-memory manipulation of graphs are [graph databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) geared towards transaction-safe, persistent storing and querying of [graph-structured data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)).